# Windows 10: Remove Program Folders from Documents Folder

Tags: windows-10, user-folders

Windows seems to allow programs to add folders to my documents folder (adobe, blackmagic, mygames, etc.). This results in a very cluttered Documents Folder that only has one or two folders that I've created. Is there a way to redirect these program folders to somewhere else preferably hidden? Deleting them or moving them manually doesn't work.

Comment: Your programs are doing it not Windows.

Comment: Agreed with @user1292580 .. these programs are given permissions to run amok using your credentials.  Stopping them will require creativity and finesse which you may or may not have.

Answer (score 0):

As @user1292580 states, the app places folders where it will. See if there is a setting in each application that allows changing the folder... though most such apps *do not* have such an option.

However, there is a work-around, if you *do not* display hidden folders in Explorer:

- Right-click on a folder.
- Select *Properties*.
- Set the *Hidden* attribute.
- Apply the changes to the folder itself.

[image: Hide a folder]

AFAIK, this should have *no* effect on the functionality of *any* application.

Two *caveats*:

- This only works if you do not display *Hidden* folders.
- On update or reinstallation, an application might recreate the folder without being *Hidden*... but you can reapply that setting to the folder.

Comment: Thank you, it looks a lot cleaner now!